# use c++ preprocessor to autogenerate repetitive code

Tags: c++, for-loop, preprocessor, variadic-macros

I'm currently dealing with a piece of extremely repetitive code that is implementing and instantiating a series of template constructors. The general pattern is somewhat like this:

```
// preamble: some dummy classes to work with
class A{};
class B{};
class C{};
class D{};
class E{};
class F{};
class G{};

class X{};
class Y{};

// the actual class declaration, located in some header file

class MyClass {
  A* _a;
  B* _b;
  C* _c;
  D* _d;
  E* _e;
  F* _f;
  G* _g;

 public:
  template<class T> void foo(const std::vector<T>& args){};

  MyClass(A* a = NULL, B* b = NULL, C* c = NULL, D* d = NULL, E* e = NULL, F* f = NULL, G* g = NULL);
  template<class T> MyClass(A* a, B* b, C* c, D* d, E* e, F* f, G* g, std::vector<T> args1);
  template<class T> MyClass(A* a, B* b, C* c, D* d, E* e, F* f, std::vector<T> args1);
  template<class T> MyClass(A* a, B* b, C* c, D* d, E* e, std::vector<T> args1);
  template<class T> MyClass(A* a, B* b, C* c, D* d, std::vector<T> args1);
  template<class T> MyClass(A* a, B* b, C* c, std::vector<T> args1);
  template<class T> MyClass(A* a, B* b, std::vector<T> args1);
  template<class T> MyClass(A* a, std::vector<T> args1);
  template<class T> MyClass(std::vector<T> args1);
};

// default constructor, this is still fine 

MyClass::MyClass(A* a, B* b, C* c, D* d, E* e, F* f, G* g) : _a(a),_b(b),_c(c),_d(c),_e(e),_f(f),_g(g) {};

// here the horribly repetitive part begins
// there are lots of repetitions of this block, every time with a slightly different signature

template<class T> MyClass(A* a, B* b, C* c, D* d, E* e, F* f, G* g, std::vector<T> args1) : MyClass(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) {
  foo<T>(args);
}
template MyClass<X>(A*, B*, C*, D*, E*, F*, G*, std::vector<X> args1);
template MyClass<Y>(A*, B*, C*, D*, E*, F*, G*, std::vector<Y> args1);

template<class T> MyClass(A* a, B* b, C* c, D* d, E* e, F* f, std::vector<T> args1) : MyClass(a,b,c,d,e,f) {
  foo<T>(args);
}
template MyClass<X>(A*, B*, C*, D*, E*, F*, std::vector<X> args1);
template MyClass<Y>(A*, B*, C*, D*, E*, F*, std::vector<Y> args1);

template<class T> MyClass(A* a, B* b, C* c, D* d, E* e, std::vector<T> args1) : MyClass(a,b,c,d,e) {
  foo<T>(args);
}
template MyClass<X>(A*, B*, C*, D*, E*, std::vector<X> args1);
template MyClass<Y>(A*, B*, C*, D*, E*, std::vector<Y> args1);

template<class T> MyClass(A* a, B* b, C* c, D* d, std::vector<T> args1) : MyClass(a,b,c,d) {
  foo<T>(args);
}
template MyClass<X>(A*, B*, C*, D*, std::vector<X> args1);
template MyClass<Y>(A*, B*, C*, D*, std::vector<Y> args1);

template<class T> MyClass(A* a, B* b, C* c, std::vector<T> args1) : MyClass(a,b,c) {
  foo<T>(args);
}
template MyClass<X>(A*, B*, C*, std::vector<X> args1);
template MyClass<Y>(A*, B*, C*, std::vector<Y> args1);

template<class T> MyClass(A* a, B* b, std::vector<T> args1) : MyClass(a,b) {
  foo<T>(args);
}
template MyClass<X>(A*, B*, std::vector<X> args1);
template MyClass<Y>(A*, B*, std::vector<Y> args1);

template<class T> MyClass(A* a, std::vector<T> args1) : MyClass(a) {
  foo<T>(args);
}
template MyClass<X>(A*, std::vector<X> args1);
template MyClass<Y>(A*, std::vector<Y> args1);

template<class T> MyClass(A* a, std::vector<T> args1) : MyClass() {
  foo<T>(args);
}
template MyClass<X>(std::vector<X> args1);
template MyClass<Y>(std::vector<Y> args1);

// here some main function just to make it compile    

int main(){
  std::vector<X> x;
  MyClass c(NULL,NULL,NULL,x);
  return 1;
}
```

As you can see, there is a specific type of block that is repeated over and over again

```
template<class T> MyClass(ARG* arg, ..., const std::vector<T> &args) : Myclass(arg,...) { foo<T>(args); } 
template MyClass<X>(ARG* arg, ..., const std::vector<X>& args)
template MyClass<Y>(ARG* arg, ..., const std::vector<Y>& args)
```

This code is, of course, a nightmare to maintain, and I find myself repeatedly using `sed` to edit the code, which is of course bad practice and bound to fail at some point.

I think the repetition could be abstracted away using some preprocessor macro

```
#define GENERATE_CONSTRUCTOR(...) ???

GENERATE_CONSTRUCTOR(A,a,B,b,C,c,D,d)
```

I would imagine that it would be possible to write `GENERATE_CONSTRUCTOR`  as some variadic preprocessor macro with a `FOREACH` loop, but unfortunately, all the documentation I could find on the topic of variadic preprocessor macros was highly confusing to me, and not terribly helpful since most examples are centered around some technique to wrap `printf`.

What would be a nice way to abstract away such repetitive code segments, possibly using preprocessor magic?

Comment: `boost` has some kind of preprocessor `FOREACH` macro helper.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template

Comment: Aside: why not one constructor `template<class T> MyClass(std::vector<T> args = {}, A* a = NULL, B* b = NULL, C* c = NULL, D* d = NULL, E* e = NULL, F* f = NULL, G* g = NULL);`?

Comment: @Caleth: good suggestion actually. In the specific scenario at hand, this is not an option because `A`, `B`, `C`, etc. partially inherit from each other, such that in some circumstances, the final object is needed to resolve confusing ambiguities in the way the function is called, but this is not a very good design anyway, so thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

My skills aren't enough to attempt variadic macros, but you can remove a lot of the repetitive code via regular old non-variadic macros, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

#define PARAMS_1 A* a,                                     std::vector<T> args1
#define PARAMS_2 A* a, B* b,                               std::vector<T> args1
#define PARAMS_3 A* a, B* b, C* c,                         std::vector<T> args1
#define PARAMS_4 A* a, B* b, C* c, D* d,                   std::vector<T> args1
#define PARAMS_5 A* a, B* b, C* c, D* d, E* e,             std::vector<T> args1
#define PARAMS_6 A* a, B* b, C* c, D* d, E* e, F* f,       std::vector<T> args1
#define PARAMS_7 A* a, B* b, C* c, D* d, E* e, F* f, G* g, std::vector<T> args1

#define ARGS_1 a
#define ARGS_2 a,b
#define ARGS_3 a,b,c
#define ARGS_4 a,b,c,d
#define ARGS_5 a,b,c,d,e
#define ARGS_6 a,b,c,d,e,f
#define ARGS_7 a,b,c,d,e,f,g

#define DECLAREHEADER(x) template<class T> MyClass(PARAMS_##x)

// preamble: some dummy classes to work with
class A{};
class B{};
class C{};
class D{};
class E{};
class F{};
class G{};

class X{};
class Y{};

// the actual class declaration, located in some header file
class MyClass {
  A* _a;
  B* _b;
  C* _c;
  D* _d;
  E* _e;
  F* _f;
  G* _g;

 public:
  template<class T> void foo(const std::vector<T>& args){};

  MyClass(A* a = NULL, B* b = NULL, C* c = NULL, D* d = NULL, E* e = NULL, F* f = NULL, G* g = NULL);

  DECLAREHEADER(7);
  DECLAREHEADER(6);
  DECLAREHEADER(5);
  DECLAREHEADER(4);
  DECLAREHEADER(3);
  DECLAREHEADER(2);
  DECLAREHEADER(1);
};

// default constructor, this is still fine
MyClass::MyClass(A* a, B* b, C* c, D* d, E* e, F* f, G* g) : _a(a),_b(b),_c(c),_d(d),_e(e),_f(f),_g(g) {}

#define DECLAREALL(x) template<class T> MyClass :: MyClass(PARAMS_##x) : MyClass(ARGS_##x) { foo<T>(args1); }

DECLAREALL(7);
DECLAREALL(6);
DECLAREALL(5);
DECLAREALL(4);
DECLAREALL(3);
DECLAREALL(2);
DECLAREALL(1);

int main(){
  std::vector<X> x;
  MyClass c(NULL,NULL,NULL,x);
  return 1;
}
```

Note that I omitted the `template MyClass<X>` and `template MyClass<Y>` lines because I wasn't sure what their intent was, but you should be able to add them back into the `DECLAREALL` macro's definition easily enough.